# Python final exam task (data structure)

Tags: python, dictionary

I am confused, can I put dictionaries within dictionaries? Can I put lists within dictionaries? How do I access the data?

Can anyone help me by giving me a solution to this problem so I can play about with it and learn how it works?

[image]

I already have a solution to the first part

```
def common (x,y):
    z=0
    for i in x:
        for p in y:
            if p==i:
                z=z+1
    return z
```

This works and I understand how/why it works.

I'm not sure what data structures to use or how to work with them, can anyone help me out?

Comment: I recommend the book 'Learning Python', by Mark Lutz if you need to get up to speed. I'm afraid there are no shortcuts, and people here solving the problems for you won't really make you learn anything I'm afraid :-(

Comment: +1 for Lutz! The answer to your first question is: yes, you can put both lists and dictionaries inside dictionaries (although only as values, not as keys; they are both mutable and unhashable). You should also learn about the `set`, as `common` can be implemented as `set(x).intersection(y)` as long as `x` and `y` contain hashable items.

Comment: I will look into the book thank you, the book we have for our course doesn't seem to answer any of my questions. I will try to work with that, thank you for the recommendation! 
Thank you, someone has left an example below and I think I am understanding how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to figure out what does these code mean by yourself. I just give you some hints.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

a = {1:2}
aa = [1,2,3]
b = {1:a}
c = {2:aa}

print b[1][1]
print c[2][0]
```

Comment: Ah okay, so for B it would go to the key '1' and then again to the key 1 in the a dictionary, so the answer would be 2? And for C is would go to the key 2 and then the 1st (0) member of the aa list so it would be 1? Thank you :D

Comment: @Rachel Welcome! And you'd better follow Carpetsmoker's advice, giving yourself a solid base of Python.